# How to Scroll Right with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't figure out how to scroll the page in mouseover, the ''.puntatore3'' is the div that i need to use as button to scroll the body to the right.

I set the body to 4000 x 4000 and 4 div to use as a hover to navigate like an infinite world on the page. But I noticed that there is no scrollRight (). If you can give me a hand on how to do this calculation. I tried to do some calculations like subtracting the width from the page to scrollLeft () but it doesn't seem to work well

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    // change this value as per your need
    var distancePerSec = 1000;
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
    $(this).scrollLeft(0);

    $(".puntatore1").hover(function() {

      var h = $("body").height();
      var targetScrollTop = 0;
      var distanceToTravel = $(window).scrollTop();
      var animationDuration = (distanceToTravel / distancePerSec) * 1000;

      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: targetScrollTop
      }, animationDuration, 'linear');

    }, function() {

      // stop the animation
      $("html, body").stop();

    });

    $(".puntatore2").hover(function() {

      var h = $("body").height();
      var targetScrollTop = h - $(window).height();
      var distanceToTravel = targetScrollTop - $(window).scrollTop();
      var animationDuration = (distanceToTravel / distancePerSec) * 1000;

      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: targetScrollTop
      }, animationDuration, 'linear');

    }, function() {

      // stop the animation
      $("html, body").stop();

    });

    $(".puntatore3").hover(function() {

      var h = $("body").width();
      var targetScrollTop = $(window).width() - $(window).scrollLeft();
      var distanceToTravel = targetScrollTop - $(window).scrollLeft();
      var animationDuration = 100;

      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollLeft: targetScrollTop
      }, animationDuration, 'linear');

    }, function() {

      // stop the animation
      $("html, body").stop();

    });

    $(".puntatore4").hover(function() {

      var h = $("body").height();
      var targetScrollTop = h - $(window).height();
      var distanceToTravel = targetScrollTop - $(window).scrollLeft();
      var animationDuration = (distanceToTravel / distancePerSec) * 1000;

      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollLeft: targetScrollTop
      }, animationDuration, 'linear');

    }, function() {

      // stop the animation
      $("html, body").stop();

    });

  });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 4000px;
    height: 4000px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.contenitore .puntatore1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.contenitore .puntatore2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.contenitore .puntatore3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.contenitore .puntatore4 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}


.try {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="contenitore">
    <div class="puntatore1"></div>
    <div class="puntatore2"></div>
    <div class="puntatore3"></div>
    <div class="puntatore4"></div>
</div>

<div class="try">
    CIAO
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Also your code is very non-DRY. You should delegate or give them a different ID and all the same class then you can do ONE function `$(".puntatore").hover(function() { if (this.id==="p1") ... })`

Comment: Posted html and css too

Comment: I know it's not clean but it's a test I can't get the pointer to move left the puntatore3

Comment: You seem to be missing scrollLeft: targetScrollLeft in `$("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: targetScrollTop,
      scrollLeft: targetScrollLeft
    },`

Comment: i dont understand.. i see the code posted before and doesnt work well